# Thermal radiation of black fabric

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, radiation

I'm planning to do some experiment about temperature distribution on the surface of materials, so I need to reduce the radiation from the wall behind.

What I'm going to use is a black fabric. For this purpose, can I use just normal black fabric that I can get easily?
If not, is there a certain kind of fabric for this purpose?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4JIucOs.jpg]

Comment: Are you concerned with thermal radiation, or specular reflection of other sources?   That affects the answer.